# EF Code First Migrations: recreate database and Seed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6.1

I'm using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` initializer and `Seed` method in `DbMigrationConfiguration`:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "...";
    }

    protected override void Seed(Context context)
    {
        context.MyEntities.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, new[]
        {
            new MyEntity { Name = "Name 1" },
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Automatic migration works fine with an existing database. But when there is no existing database (*.mdf, LocalDb), on first application start initializer only calls `Up()` methods from `DbMigration` without `Seed`. `Seed` method is called only after application restart.

If I manually call `Upgrade-Database` before first start it will create database and `Seed` method will be called on first run.

How to automatically initialize database with Seed data on application start when there is no existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will really solve your problem:

[Using Entity Framework Code First Migrations to auto-create and auto-update an application](http://galleryserverpro.com/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-to-auto-create-and-auto-update-an-application/)

In this code, after the database initialization, an instance of `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator` is used to manually apply all pending migrations.

The problem with this solution is that you need an initial migration. Although in the linked article it's not explained, I think that you can create an initial migration against an empty database by creating it from Nuget console before enabling automatic migrations.

Comment: Updated link: http://galleryserverpro.com/using-entity-framework-code-first-migrations-to-auto-create-and-auto-update-an-application/